# Wordpress admin deleted user details not removed in database. How to delete WordPress Users from Database

Tags: plugin-development, users, user-meta

When we delete a user from the WordPress admin panel it's removed, but the user values not deleted in the database.

Anyone let me know how to fix the issue. ?

What is the reason for this issue.?

Comment: What values? Metadata? Did you enable debugging and check the error logs?

Comment: @SallyCJ I want to  delete in wp-user & wp-usermeta table.

Comment: Well, if the user was indeed removed, then there should be no more entries for that user in the users table. Regarding the user meta table, you could run something like `DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id NOT IN ( SELECT ID FROM wp_users )` at your own risks.. and after backing up the database.